# Easy Auth returns empty response for some people

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I'm using the `/.auth/me` endpoint to get claims for the users.

I'm obtaining the Bearer token in order to authenticate to the endpoint.

The endpoint itself is on an Azure Function origin, so what I'm calling is https://azure_function_name.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me with the `Authorization` header set to `Bearer (token)`

This works but not for all people.

Some people get the following response from the `/.auth/me` endpoint:

```
[]
```

Why the `/.auth/me` endpoint returns a valid response for some tokens (people) and an empty response for other?

Comment: How did you get the access token?

Comment: AFAIK `Easy Auth` is a WIP https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/33

Comment: Do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Comment: @TonyJu The access token comes from the `Authorization` header from the request object from the Azure function entry point.

Comment: What I noticed, if you are already authenticated, and enable the Token Store on your App Service, you will need to log off and re-authenticate to create the store for the user.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [OAuth 2.0 auth code grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code)(with a user login) to get the access token. And I can get the correct response with endpoint `/.auth/me`. I have tried both Member or Guest users in my tenant.

You can try to access https://azure_function_name.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me directly. You will get the response after logging in.

The reply url should be `https://azure_function_name.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback`

[image]

Comment: Actually, when I'm navigating to that endpoint in a browser I get `The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application` error but I don't think it really matters since some people are getting their claims and some other are getting empty array as a response, but all of them are getting the `200 OK`

Comment: @Szybki can you check the reply url? I have updated my answer. It is strange.  'The access token comes from the Authorization header from the request object from the Azure function entry point.' Did you get the access token after logging in?

Comment: Unfortunately no, not at all. I worked this around to just check if I get whether 200 OK or 401 unauthorized response in order to validate if the user is authenticated. I still don't have a clue why for some tokens I get empty array in the response body.