# Azure /.auth/me Service Endpoint sometimes returning "[]" empty array

Tags: azure, authentication, authorization

Sometimes the /.auth/me Service endpoint returns [], it's difficult to replicate the issue.

I tried to idle for 1 hour and when I get back and refresh the page it only redirects me to login page only but not returning empty array "[]".

I wanted to capture how and when /.auth/me returns empty array "[]"
I wanted to know what the cause of this is, and how to solve it?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/56111020/5085211

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE - 2022-12-31:**

It seems that the behavior has changed — at least in my case. Originally, sending an invalid AppServiceAuthSession cookie will result in an empty array response from /.auth/me; Now, /.auth/me does not respond with an empty array; instead, it behaves as if the cookie is still valid.

In my testing, /.auth/me only responds with an empty array when there is an invalid AppServiceAuthSession cookie, *and* when I am logged out of the identity provider (Auth0 in my case).

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

From my testing, an empty array is returned when there is an invalid AppServiceAuthSession cookie sent along with the request. However, after logging back in to the Web App, the previously invalid cookie becomes valid again.

To replicate:

1. Ensure you are logged in to your Azure Web App
2. In the Web App, open developer tools and open the network tab
3. Visit /.auth/me, then inspect the request in the network tab.
    [You should see the cookie in the request headers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfauc.png)

4. Copy the cookie and try loading /.auth/me in an HTTP client such as Postman. Set the "Cookie" header to the copied cookie from network tools. In my case with Postman, the page loads perfectly fine.
5. Back in the web browser, sign out of the Web App by going to /.auth/logout; in my case, there are no redirects, so I am now greeted by the "You have been signed out" screen. Note that the server responds with the AppServiceAuthSession cookie being deleted.
6. In Postman, run the request again. Do not change any params, most especially the Cookie header. /.auth/me returns an empty array.
7. Back in the browser, log back in to the Web App. Open network tools then visit /.auth/me again. Note that there is a new AppServiceAuthSession cookie.
8. In Postman, without changing any params, send the request to /.auth/me again. Now, /.auth/me is no longer empty.

From the top of my head, some potential solutions are ensuring the AppServiceAuthSession cookie is deleted from the client's memory upon log-out (which /.auth/me is supposed to be doing anyway, but perhaps there's something in the client side preventing that — such as what was happening in my case); or redirecting the user to /.auth/logout when an empty array is detected then making them log-in again.

Comment: Thank you Julian Patdu, I'm able to replicate the issue. this is very helpful.